# Need help with tautology proof without truth tables.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I am trying to prove

$$[(p\to q)~\&~(q\to r)]\to (p\to r) $$

is a tautology using only logical laws. I have gotten part-way there but I got stuck and am not sure how to proceed.

Please state any laws that you use in your answers so that I can reference them.

```
~ = NOT
& = AND
V = OR
-> = IMPLIES
```

The Proof:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
[(p\to q)~\&~(q\to r)]\to (p\to r); & \text{Given} \\
\sim[(\sim p\vee q)~\&~({\sim} q\vee r)]~\vee~({\sim} p\vee r); & \text{Material Implication} \\
[{\sim}({\sim} p~\vee~ q)\vee{\sim}({\sim} q\vee r)]\vee({\sim} p\vee r); & \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
[(p~\&\,{\sim} q)\vee(q~\&\,{\sim} r)]\vee({\sim} p\vee r); & \text{DeMorgan's Law}
\end{array}$$

Comment: You can remove the `[]` and the `()` around `~pVr` because `V` is associative.

Comment: after that, would I be able to do p & (~q V q) & r ?

Comment: No, because `V` and `&` do not work together _that_ nicely.

Comment: yeah... that's what I thought. Would've been nice if I could.

Yeah... I have no idea how to simplify this down more so it could easily be seen that this would only evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove redundant brackets because `V` is associative:

```
(p&~q)V(q&~r)V~pVr
```

Then rearrange a little since `V` is commutative:

```
 ~pV(p&~q)VrV(q&~r)
```

Then we distribute the first two terms, and we distribute the last two:

```
[(~pVp)&(~pV~q)]V[(rVq)&(rV~r)]
```

We can cancel `(~pVp)` and `(rV~r)` because they're both tautologies (I don't know what you call that law) and because `&`-ing with a tautology doesn't change anything (I don't know what you call that law). Then again remove redundant brackets to get

```
~pV~qVrVq
```

and you should be able to see why this is a tautology.

Comment: Thanks. This worked out. I should hopefully have no trouble solving the rest of the proofs I have to do.

Also, the first rule I believe is called the "Negation Law" and the second is called the "Identity Law"

Answer (score 0):

Your next two steps:

- $(p\&\lnot q)\lor(q\&\lnot r)\lor\lnot p\lor r$ by association.
- $\lnot p\lor (p\&\lnot q)\lor(q\&\lnot r)\lor r$ by commutation.

Comment: Distribute the disjunction of $\lnot p$ over the nearest conjunction.  $\neg p\lor (p\;\& \neg q) \equiv (\neg p\lor p)\;\&(\neg p\lor\neg q)$ . Likewise distribute the disjunction of $r$ over the nearest conjunction.